# how to set condition less than or equal to jinja template

Tags: jinja2

I am new to jinja templating, I am in a situation to either print day or days,
so if `{{count}}` is 1 it should  render day but if `{{count}}` greater than 1 then it should render days

through some digging on google I tried this:

`{ 'day' if {{count}} is less than or equal to 1 else 'days' }}` but it doesnt work.

I also tried multiline:

```
        {% if count > 1 %}
        days
        {% else %}
        day
        {% endif %}
```

but that too doesnt work

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code
`{{ 'day' if count>=1 else 'days' }}`